# How to restrict sending order emails to customers in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created one payment method and it's working fine. When an order is placed, by default, an email is sent, but I want to prevent that only when my own payment method is used. I do not want an email to be sent when a user selects my payment method and clicks on the `place an order` button.

Which file, function or which event is used to send an email once user clicks on `place an order` button?

Comment: $orders ->getEmailSent() you can able restrict the user to sending the emails.

Answer (score 0):

This event is triggered in Checkout/controllers/OnePageController/SuccessAction.
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'); //line 197

I suggest please look for the files below and the methods

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

```
public function successAction(){...
   Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId))); ...
```

}

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

```
public function saveOrder(){... 
   $order->sendNewOrderEmail(); ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 files where your need to update.

For onestepcheckout: `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php`

Update `public function saveOrder()`

Remove:
`$order->sendNewOrderEmail();`

Add:

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethod()!="YOUR_CUSTOM_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME") {
    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
}
```

For multishippingcheckout: `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Multishipping.php`

Update public `function createOrders()`

Remove:
`$order->sendNewOrderEmail();`

Add:

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethod()!="YOUR_CUSTOM_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME") {
    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
}
```

Hope will help!